# Need an example for how Go syntax for assignment operator uses the grammar rules specified using EBNF

Tags: go, ebnf

[As mentioned in the docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec), syntax in Go is specified using Extended Backus-Naur Form (EBNF):

```
Production  = production_name "=" [ Expression ] "." .
Expression  = Alternative { "|" Alternative } .
Alternative = Term { Term } .
Term        = production_name | token [ "…" token ] | Group | Option | Repetition .
Group       = "(" Expression ")" .
Option      = "[" Expression "]" .
Repetition  = "{" Expression "}" .
```

I am trying to understand how Go syntax grammar is defined, how to breakdown/derive/understand the expression `i++` and `i+=1` using these grammar rules. How would these production rules be substituted step by step for the purpose of illustration?

Comment: What you are looking for is described [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDec_statements).

Comment: what would be production_name and Term in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `i++` uses the grammar rule for [IncDec statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDec_statements):

```
IncDecStmt = Expression ( "++" | "--" ) .
```

Here, `production_name` would be `IncDecStmt` and `Term` would be `"++"` or `"--"`.